# Check if element is between 30% and 60% of the viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, viewport

I am trying to change the color of `<li>` elements when they are between 30% and 60% of the viewport.

So I have this grid of elements stacking side by side like this:

[image: elements stacking side by side]

I ran into few plugins like Waypoints, Viewport Checker and few others but nothing good.

Any idea?

I am using a pretty simple structure :

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bastienleprince/h7pwo64h/2/)

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
    <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul {
    margin: auto;
}
ul li {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
}

ul li.middleviewport{
    background:red;
}
```

Comment: Please provide some source code to work on

Comment: Nice visual question, just add the code like @AndreaLigios mentioned and your question is perfect.

Comment: I am creating a jsfiddle! Sorry for the lack of elements, it's still in early stage.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

1. Use `scroll` event handler on `window`
2. Loop over all the `li` elements to check if the element is in the interested viewport
3. Get the `li` position from `top` and check if it is in the interested viewport section.

[**Demo:**](https://jsfiddle.net/atcwL1mz/)

Changed the height of `li` for demo purpose.

See the comments inline in the code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Get viewport height, gridTop and gridBottom
  var windowHeight = $(window).height(),
    gridTop = windowHeight * .3,
    gridBottom = windowHeight * .6;

  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    // On each scroll check if `li` is in interested viewport
    $('ul li').each(function() {
      var thisTop = $(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop(); // Get the `top` of this `li`

      // Check if this element is in the interested viewport
      if (thisTop >= gridTop && (thisTop + $(this).height()) <= gridBottom) {
        $(this).css('background', 'red');
      } else {
        $(this).css('background', 'gray');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
ul li {
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px
}
ul li.middleviewport {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
  <li>13</li>
  <li>14</li>
  <li>15</li>
  <li>16</li>
  <li>17</li>
  <li>18</li>
  <li>19</li>
  <li>20</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
  <li>13</li>
  <li>14</li>
  <li>15</li>
  <li>16</li>
  <li>17</li>
  <li>18</li>
  <li>19</li>
  <li>20</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
  <li>13</li>
  <li>14</li>
  <li>15</li>
  <li>16</li>
  <li>17</li>
  <li>18</li>
  <li>19</li>
  <li>20</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
  <li>13</li>
  <li>14</li>
  <li>15</li>
  <li>16</li>
  <li>17</li>
  <li>18</li>
  <li>19</li>
  <li>20</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 9):

Improved @Tushar's solution to make it work even after a resize of the window (a recalculation of the viewport is necessary each time, not only at the beginning), and to make it start already highlighted, without the need to scroll.

Also improved a bit the graphic of the example to highlight the interested area.

[Running demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AndreaLigios/h7pwo64h/5/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var windowHeight = $(window).height(),
      gridTop = windowHeight * .3,
      gridBottom = windowHeight * .6;
    $('ul li').each(function() {
      var thisTop = $(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();

      if (thisTop > gridTop && (thisTop + $(this).height()) < gridBottom) {
        $(this).css('background', 'red');
      } else {
        $(this).css('background', 'silver');
      }
    });

  });
  $(window).trigger('scroll');
});
```

```css
ul {
  margin: auto;
}
ul li {
  width: 300px;
  height: 10px;
  background: silver;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  list-style: none;
}
ul li.middleviewport {
  background: red;
}
#viewportMask {
  position: fixed;
  top: 30%;
  bottom: 40%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: red;
  opacity: 0.2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="viewportMask"></div>
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Good! 1 problem when user is never going to resize the window, this will be bit slower. Instead of triggering `scroll`, you can call the callback by invoking it `function() {}());` like this.

Comment: $(window).on().trigger() can be used too. (chaining)

Answer (score 2):

**[[ This example checks if ANY part of the element is inside the specified region ]]**

When you have the top and bottom coordinates of two boxes, you can check if the two boxes overlap by checking:

```
box1.top < box2.bottom && box1.bottom > box2.top
```

In the following example, box1 is the 30%-60% portion of window while box2 is each list item. Add debounce function and we have:

```js
var timeout;
$(window).on("load scroll resize", function() {
  if (timeout) {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
  }
  timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    var $window = $(window),
      hitbox_top = $window.scrollTop() + $window.height() * .3,
      hitbox_bottom = $window.scrollTop() + $window.height() * .6;
    $("li").each(function() {
      var $element = $(this),
        element_top = $element.offset().top,
        element_bottom = $element.offset().top + $element.height();
      $element.toggleClass("middle-viewport", hitbox_top < element_bottom && hitbox_bottom > element_top);
    });
  }, 200);
});
```

```css
#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 30%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 192, 255, .5);
}
ul {
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
li.middle-viewport {
  background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="overlay"></div>
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was free to create a plugin for this. Within options you can set percents, css class, trigger event and execution delay (css changed to responsive for presentation only):

```js
jQuery.fn.extend({
 markInViewport: function (options) {
  var that = this;
  this.defaults = {
   percentTop: 30,
   percentBottom: 40,
   cssClass: 'middleviewport',
   event: 'scroll resize',
   delay: 10
  };
  this.options = $.extend(that.defaults, options);
  this.win = $(window);
  this.delayChecking = null;
  this.items = [];
  this.checkItems = function (items) {
   clearTimeout(that.delayChecking);
   that.delayChecking = setTimeout(function () {
    var thisWindowHeight = that.win.height();
    var thisWindowScrollTop = that.win.scrollTop();
    that.items.each(function (j) {
     var thisItem = $(this);
     var thisItemHeight = thisItem.outerHeight();
     var thisItemPositionTop = thisItem.offset().top;
     var currentPercentTop = (thisItemPositionTop - thisWindowScrollTop) / thisWindowHeight * 100;
     var currentPercentBottom = (thisWindowScrollTop + thisWindowHeight - thisItemPositionTop - thisItemHeight) / thisWindowHeight * 100;
     thisItem.toggleClass(that.options.cssClass, currentPercentTop >= that.options.percentTop && currentPercentBottom >= that.options.percentBottom);
    });
   }, that.options.delay);
  };
  return this.each(function () {
   that.items = that.children();
   $(window).on(that.options.event, that.checkItems);
   that.checkItems();
  });
 }
});
$('.check_viewport').markInViewport();
```

```css
ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}
ul li {
    width: 32.73%;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 3.5%; /* responsive height */
    background: #f5f5f5;
    float: left;
    margin: .3%;
    list-style:none;
}
ul li.middleviewport {
    background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <ul class="check_viewport">
        <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

**[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/h7pwo64h/9/)**

Answer (score 0):

Create a div width `width:100%` and `height:100%` that represent the viewport. Inside this div you place your grid system.

Than you need to use jquery `.position()`  [jquery position](http://api.jquery.com/position/)

```
var grid = $( "griddiv's" );
var position = grid.position();
var height = $('parentdiv').height();
lower = 0.3 * height;
upper = 0.6 * height;

if(grid.top >= lower && grid.top <= upper){
  $('gridcell').css('background','red');
}
```

I didn't test it but I hope it works