# Detect when scrolled to last li

Tags: jquery, html, viewport

I need to check if the user has scrolled to the end of a list item `<li>` on my page. I want to perform an *AJAX* call, when this happens.

How to know if the user has scrolled to the last list item.

This is what I've tried till now.

```
if ($('li:last').is(':visible')) {
    alert('Scrolled to last li');
}
```

But, unfortunately it is not working.

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29891587/check-if-element-is-between-30-and-60-of-the-viewport/29892258#29892258

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a function like this:

```
function isElementVisible(elem)
{
    var $elem = $(elem);
    var $window = $(window);

    var docViewTop = $window.scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $window.height();

    var elemTop = $elem.offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $elem.height();

    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}
```

And handle the scroll event:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
    var e = $('#yourContiner ul li:last');
    if (isElementVisible(e)) {
        alert('visible');
    }
    })
})
```

Comment: A small issue. This alerts 2 times when last li is visible. Why?

Comment: Because of the scroll event. When each pixel is scrolled the event is fired and probably is show the alert more than on time. You can control with a variable tha can be set on the first time your element is visible.

Comment: I did a simple jsfiddle to solve the problem with the event firing many times: http://jsfiddle.net/ehta1x3e/

Answer (score 1):

You cannot check if the element is `visible`, because even if the element is not in the viewport it is still visible.

From jQuery Docs:

> Elements are considered visible if they consume space in the document. Visible elements have a width or height that is greater than zero.

Tweaked my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29892258/2025923) little bit.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/atcwL1mz/24/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Get window height, and the bottom of the viewport
  var windowHeight = $(window).height(),
    gridTop = windowHeight * .1,
    gridBottom = windowHeight + $('ul li:last').height();


  // On each scroll event on window
  $(window).on('scroll', function() {

    // Interested element caching
    var $lastElement = $('ul li:last');
    // Get elemets top
    var thisTop = $lastElement.offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();


    // Check if the element is in the current viewport
    if (thisTop > gridTop && (thisTop + $lastElement.height()) < gridBottom) {
      $('#message').text('Yay! In sight');
      $lastElement.addClass('middleviewport');
    } else {
      $('#message').text('Still not available');
      $lastElement.removeClass('middleviewport');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#message {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2;
  background: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  color: red;
}
ul {
  margin: auto;
}
ul li {
  width: 300px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}
ul li.middleviewport {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="message">Still not available</div>
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```