# How to select visible elements in scrolling list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to select elements currently `visible` (and in view) in scrolling list. In my list I have a `table`. Example:

```
<div class='list'>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>item</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>item</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>item</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>item</td>
    </tr>        
</table>
```

I want to only choose those elements that are now in visible to the user (ie. on the screen, not off screen)

[image]

On JsFiddle: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/skriming/stb0sd71/)

Comment: THis is working what is the problem?

Comment: all elements are visible

Comment: No, this select all elements in table, not only visible.

Comment: what you really mean by `visible` ??

Comment: im guessing the user asks for the elements that are currently in view? As opposed to those outside the scrolling area. The question is wheter half-visible elements should be chosen also.

Comment: Please see my answer.

Comment: @AmitSoni Those which are completely visible

Comment: Do you mean the elements that are currently in view?

Comment: what if any element is `half visible` ??

Comment: @AmitSoni They must also be selected

Comment: @skriming Check this [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/stb0sd71/2/)

Comment: @Tushar thank you. this work for me good! you can create answer if u want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tweaked my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29891587/check-if-element-is-between-30-and-60-of-the-viewport/29892258#29892258)

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/stb0sd71/2/)

See comments inline in the code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Get viewport height, gridTop and gridBottom
  var gridTop = 0,
    gridBottom = $('.list').outerHeight();

  $('.list').on('scroll', function() {
    // On each scroll check if `td` is in interested viewport
    $('.list td').each(function() {
      var thisTop = $(this).offset().top;

      // Check if this element is in the interested viewport
      if (thisTop >= gridTop && (thisTop + $(this).height()) <= gridBottom) {
        $(this).css('background', 'red');
      } else {
        $(this).css('background', 'gray');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.list {
  height: 112px;
  width: 300px;
  display: block;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
table tr td {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: gray;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='list'>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>item</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>item</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>item</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>item</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>item</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>item</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>item</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>item</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>item</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>item</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>item</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>item</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>item</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>item</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>item</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>item</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer here provides a function to detect if an element is within scrollable view, iterate you elements and check against the function

[Check if element is visible after scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling)

EDIT: with some adjustment this code works (it could be refactored, but shows the concept): https://jsfiddle.net/vas840kr/

```
var $window = $(".list");
var docViewTop = $window.scrollTop();
var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $window.height() + 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you:

```js
$('tr:first-child td, tr:nth-child(2) td').css('background', 'red');
```

Comment: But you know. There's two of them. How would you not know?!

Comment: This simple example mate :)

Answer (score 0):

I figure you're going to want to apply this to a dynamic number of td's. However, since there's no CSS selector to specifically target those elements 'hidden' from view due to overflow clipping, you'll have to use javascript to reach those elements or their inverse, in-view siblings.

Answer (score 0):

I made a pure JavaScript solution ("Vanilla JS"), as a branch of your question's jsfiddle. Maybe of interest for some readers:

https://jsfiddle.net/rplantiko/u2gLr64c/

```
(function(){

    var result = document.getElementById("result");
    var container = document.getElementById("container");
    var cells  = toArray(
       document.getElementsByTagName("td")
       );
    var isCellVisible = isChildElementVisible( container );

    container.addEventListener("scroll",determineVisibleRows);
    determineVisibleRows();

    function determineVisibleRows() {
      result.value =  
        cells.filter( isCellVisible ).map( rowIndex ).join(',');
      }

    function isChildElementVisible(container) {
      var containerHeight = parseInt(getComputedStyle(container).height);
      return function(element) {
        var containerTop = parseInt( container.scrollTop );
        var containerBottom = containerTop + containerHeight;
        var elemTop = element.offsetTop;
        var elemHeight =  parseInt(getComputedStyle(element).height);
        var elemBottom = elemTop + elemHeight;
        return (elemTop >= containerTop && 
                elemBottom <= containerBottom);
        }
     }

    function toArray(arraylikeObject) {
      return Array.prototype.slice.call( arraylikeObject, 0 )
    }

    function rowIndex( cell ) {
      return cell.parentNode.rowIndex+1;  
    }

})()
```