# Toggle class when object visible in the viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, viewport

I need a script which toggle a class when another class or section is visible in the viewport (during scrolling).

Here I have an script which works for precised distance from top, but can somebody help me to modify it for my needs?

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
      if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
          $('#viewport').addClass('turn_on');
      } else {
          $('#viewport').removeClass('turn_on');
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qbdgc2nv/48/)**

Try to add function that detect if element passed in argument is visible :

```
function isVisisble(elem){
    return $(elem).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop() < $(elem).height() ;
}

$(window).scroll(function(){
   if (isVisisble( $('your_element') ))
      $('#viewport').addClass('turn_on');
   } else {
      $('#viewport').removeClass('turn_on');
   }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work:/ Check this: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qbdgc2nv/42/)

Comment: Check the console and you can see in live HTML that the class will be added and removed depending to the scroll.

Comment: Glad to helo, You're Welcome.

Comment: remember to add a open curly brackets before first statement on if condition.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things.  First the scroll event (as well as the resize event) fire multiple times.  Traditionally, developers have used something called [debouncing](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function) to limit the number of times a function fires.  I've never got it to work correctly, so instead I check if a condition is met before continuing.  You are basically doing this already.

```
var bool = false
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
   if(!bool){
      bool = true;
      //fire the function and then turn bool back to false.
   };
});
```

The next thing you need is to identify the element to add the class to.  Let's say it has an id of `foo`.

```
var yOffset = $('#foo').offset().top;
```

From here, you'll need to compare the current vertical scroll position with that of the yOffset.  You may also need to add the height of the element for when it scrolls out of frame.

```
var elHeight = $('#foo').height();
```

The element should be completely in frame with the `$(window).scrollTop()` equals the `yOffset` and out of frame when the `$(window).scrollTop()` is greater than `yOffset + elHeight`.

This is all assuming the element isn't in the frame to begin with.  If it is, it will be trickier but it's a start.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation, my js knowledge is poor but it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clearing the basics. It really helps

Answer (score 1):

Thx everyone for help. 
Here I found the solution: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29891587/check-if-element-is-between-30-and-60-of-the-viewport)

And here is the modified script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var windowHeight = $(window).height(),
        gridTop = windowHeight * 0.1,
        gridBottom = windowHeight * 1;
    $(window).on('scroll', function () {
        $('.inner').each(function () {
            var thisTop = $(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();

            if (thisTop > gridTop && (thisTop + $(this).height()) < gridBottom) {
                $(this).addClass('on');
            }  
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution. It's working for me