# JavaScript: addClass when element is in viewport using animate.css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am using animate.css which is nice and simple as I am a beginner. I can get the animation to work and can delay the animation with `animation-duration: 3s` and `animation-delay: 0s;` But I can't find how to trigger it when it comes into my viewport as I scroll down to it. Here is the code I have tried so far:

## HTML

```
<div class="about-container">
         <p>Content here...</p>
     </div>
```

## CSS

```
.about-container{
    background-color: #a3c17f;
    width: 500px;
    height:500px;
    margin: 0 auto;    
}
```

## JAVASCRIPT

```
$(function() {
   if ($("#about-container").length > 0) {
      addClass('animated pulse')
   }
});  
     </script>
```

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29892258/2025923) might help/give you idea.

Comment: This isn't working for me, I wonder if it because I am using animate.css

Comment: `about-container` is class or ID??

Comment: It's a class from animate.css, usually you add it through the class tag in html

Comment: But in `js` you are using it as `ID`

Comment: Ah yes! Goo spot, but I changed it to an `ID` and it's still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your element. You are using class. So it should be $('.about-container'). However you can change it into ID.

```
$(function() {
   if($('#about-container').length > 0) { // check if there's an element
      $('#about-container').addClass('animated pulse'); // this is how you add class in jquery
   }
});
```

Plain Javascript

```
var abtContainer = document.getElementById('about-container');

if(abtContainer.length > 0) {
    abtContainer.classList.add('animated pulse'); 
}
```

However this method don't work on IE8 and below.

So you need to use this if you are supporting old browsers.

```
abtContainer.className += ' animated pulse';
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QERZpz

Comment: I tried this too but it isn't working. Do you think it might be because it is with animate.css?

Comment: I am using Chrome.

Comment: No. It's because of your javascript. If you want to try it. Try to remove all javascript and put this $('#about-container').addClass('animated pulse'); I also used animate.css before. And that's how I do it. You need to target the element and addClass on it.

Comment: But how to I trigger it to animate only when it is in the viewport??

Comment: What do you mean of viewport? When the user is on desktop or mobile viewport?

Comment: This works but only when the page loads and not when it comes into the viewport.

Comment: Ideally I would like it to be both, so I'd imagine the easiest way would be when it is a certain amount of pixels from the top of the screen? I thought `(abtContainer.length > 0` would do the job

Comment: What you mean is, you don't want the element to overflow into the screen.  Am I right? If that's the case, you better move the element and manipulate the element after the animation. Animate.css has their documentation to oncomplete function. Maybe it can help you.

Comment: Sorry, I realise the confusion. By viewport I mean it triggers when the user scrolls down to it and it is in view since it won't be the first element on landing on the page

Comment: I updated the pen. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QERZpz You need something like this.

Comment: Brilliant. That's what I was looking for! Only thing is it only triggers once if you knew a quick fix for that otherwise that is perfect!

Comment: Updated! You just need to removeClass if you want it to.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

"OnScreen JS"

A jQuery plugin that does stuff to elements when they enter or leave the viewport

> https://silvestreh.github.io/onScreen/

Answer (score 0):

```
   function addClass(elem, clazz) {
     if (!elemHasClass(elem, clazz)) {
    elem.className += " " + clazz;
      }
    }

         function elemHasClass(elem, clazz) {
          return new RegExp("( |^)" + clazz + "( |$)").test(elem.className);
         }
```

try this

```
      jQuery('.row.homeCats').addClass("hideme").viewportChecker({
            classToAdd: 'visible animated fadeInDown',

        });
```

Comment: if you want to add class you can use this method

Comment: My problem is I can't get the css animation to trigger or add when the div is in the viewport.

Comment: Do I use both of these? I'm not familiar with any of your code so is it possible to put it into the context of the code I have given?

Comment: not the both try the bellow one if its not working just ping me

Comment: https://github.com/webknit/add-class-when-in-viewport check this link for reference bro it will be help full

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it seem you are adding  addClass('animated pulse').
Since addClass supports multiple class your code is right.
For testing your code you can try applying class like this manner .addClass('animated ').addClass('pulse');
But use $(this).addClass('animated pulse') in order to append class to '.about-container' DIV.

From your given HTML DIV you dont have ID #about-container, 
So replace ,

```
        $(function() {
         if ($(".about-container").length > 0) {
          $(this).addClass('animated pulse');   // Add class supports multiple class
    //OR
      $(this).addClass('animated'). addClass('animated'); // But try this also 
   }
   });
```